Error: The requested KieBase "normalRulesKBase" does not exist in Drools
I'm working on creating multiple KieSessions dynamically using Drools in Scala. I have two sets of rules stored in different folders (slidingwindow and normal) within the resources/rules directory. The rules are fetched from a database and written to the KieFileSystem. However, when I run the code in the Spark shell, I encounter the following error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: The requested KieBase "normalRulesKBase" does not exist
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.getKieBaseModelImpl(KieContainerImpl.java:487)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.getKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:433)
    at createKieSessionWithRules



Create two KieBases, one for each set of rules (normal and slidingwindow), and dynamically load the     rules into the KieSession from the database.
The rules are stored in the folders resources/rules/normal and resources/rules/slidingwindow respectively.
The error occurs when trying to retrieve the KieBase for the "normalRulesKBase".

Here is the relevant Scala code:
def createKieSessionWithRules(drl: String): KieSession = {
    val kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get()
    val rules = "import com.sample.model.RuleTemplate\n" + drl
    val packageDeclaration = "package rules.normal;"
    val finalDrl = if (!rules.contains("package ")) {
        s"$packageDeclaration\n$rules"
    } else {
        rules
    }

    val kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem()
    kieFileSystem.write("src/main/resources/rules/normal/normal_rules.drl", finalDrl)

    val kieBuilder: KieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem)
    kieBuilder.buildAll()

    val results = kieBuilder.getResults()
    if (results.hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Build Errors:\n" + results.toString())
    }

    val kieContainer: KieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId())
    val kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase("normalRulesKBase") // Error here
    val ksession: KieSession = kieBase.newKieSession()

    if (ksession == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create normalRulesKSession")
    } else {
        println("normalRulesKSession created successfully")
    }

    ksession
}


